# Cannot insert CAGradientLayer at index 0 (behind tableView)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, cagradientlayer

Trying to insert a layer with the custom gradient as a background for the tableView. However, it is displayed in front of the table.

It worked previously, but it doesn't work now, when I updated the XCode.

```
    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    let gradient = self.getMenuGradientLayer()

    gradient.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -statusBarHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: statusBarHeight + self.view.bounds.height)

    // Tried multiple options. Not at the same time, of course.
    self.view.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0) // Worked previously
    self.tableView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
    self.tableView.backgroundView?.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)
```

Some of those options don't display the gradient at all, some display it in the front of the table.

The class itself is *UITableViewController*.

I have tried to implement this code in *viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, viewWillLayoutSubviews*.

Same thing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found another way to execute the task using the backgroundView property of tableView.

```
    let statusBarHeight = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.height
    let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: -statusBarHeight, width: self.view.frame.width, height: statusBarHeight + self.view.bounds.height)

    let gradient = self.getMenuGradientLayer()

    gradient.frame = frame

    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: frame)

    backgroundView.layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 0)

    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
```

However, still do not understand why the previous solution stopped to work...